# Google Identity Toolkit returns "A system error has occurred" with googleplus provider

Tags: android, google-identity-toolkit

I my android app I have 2 providers: facebook and google+. There are not problems with Facebook (and password) access.
With googleplus always I have this response:

```
Response from verifyAssertion:

{"error":{
    "message":"A system error has occurred",
    "code":400,
    "errors": [
         {"message":"A system error has occurred",
          "domain":"global","reason":"invalid"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error message does not reveal much information. Could you please post your question again on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-identity-toolkit so that we can contact you in person?

Comment: the problem was the incorrect applicationId (right in androidmanifest,xml but changed in bundle.gradle)